Docker build failed with DB container exited after sometime
I have full-stack application constructed with frontend as Angular, API as ASP.NET API, database as SQL Server. I also have two dockerfile for both Angular and ASP.NET API applications. I also have docker-compose.yml file to include this three services. Now when I build those images through docker-compose file, they are all running at their expected port. After sometime, my DB container is shutting down. And also my API container is failed to build the dockerfile. I have also initial migration (entrypoint.sh) file to create the database only.
My API dockerfile is
# Use the SDK image to build and publish the app
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["PaymentAPI/PaymentAPI.csproj", "PaymentAPI/"]
RUN dotnet restore "PaymentAPI/PaymentAPI.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/PaymentAPI"
RUN dotnet build "PaymentAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build
RUN dotnet publish "PaymentAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

# Use the SDK image to run the app and perform migrations
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app/publish .
COPY --from=build /src/PaymentAPI/PaymentAPI.csproj /app/
COPY entrypoint.sh .
RUN chmod +x entrypoint.sh
RUN dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef
ENV PATH "$PATH:/root/.dotnet/tools"
ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]

The entrypoint.sh file contains (in LF formatted)
#!/bin/bash
set -e

run_cmd="dotnet PaymentAPI.dll"

until dotnet ef database update --project /app/PaymentAPI.csproj 2>&1; do
  >&2 echo "SQL Server is starting up"
  sleep 1
done

>&2 echo "SQL Server is up - executing command"
exec $run_cmd


My docker-compose.yml file contains
services:
  paymentapi:
    build:
      context: ./PaymentAPI
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5000:8080"
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
    depends_on:
      - mssql

  paymentapp:
    build:
      context: ./PaymentApp
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8044:80"
    depends_on:
      - paymentapi

  mssql:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
    environment:
      SA_PASSWORD: "YourStrong!Passw0rd"
      ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
      MSSQL_PID: "Developer"
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
    volumes:
      - mssqldata:/var/opt/mssql
      - ./mssql-init:/mssql-init
    command: >
      /bin/bash -c "
      /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr & 
      sleep 30s && 
      /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P YourStrong!Passw0rd -i /mssql-init/init-database.sql &&
      sleep 30s"

volumes:
  mssqldata:

the API container gives this error message
2024-07-04 11:02:45 Build started...
2024-07-04 11:02:47 Build failed. Use dotnet build to see the errors.
2024-07-04 11:02:47 SQL Server is starting up
2024-07-04 11:03:37 Build started...
2024-07-04 11:03:39 Build failed. Use dotnet build to see the errors.
2024-07-04 11:03:39 SQL Server is starting up

And the DB container gives this error message (not sure this is a error message)
2024-07-04 05:01:23.73 spid24s     SQL Server is now ready for client connections. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
2024-07-04 05:01:23.76 spid28s     Parallel redo is started for database 'PaymentDatabase' with worker pool size [4].
2024-07-04 05:01:23.76 Server      Common language runtime (CLR) functionality initialized.
2024-07-04 05:01:23.78 spid28s     1 transactions rolled forward in database 'PaymentDatabase' (5:0). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2024-07-04 05:01:23.80 spid12s     Clearing tempdb database.
2024-07-04 05:01:23.82 spid28s     0 transactions rolled back in database 'PaymentDatabase' (5:0). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2024-07-04 05:01:23.82 spid28s     Parallel redo is shutdown for database 'PaymentDatabase' with worker pool size [4].
2024-07-04 05:01:23.94 spid12s     [2]. Feature Status: PVS: 0. CTR: 0. ConcurrentPFSUpdate: 1.
2024-07-04 05:01:23.94 spid12s     Starting up database 'tempdb'.
2024-07-04 05:01:24.50 spid12s     The tempdb database has 8 data file(s).
2024-07-04 05:01:24.51 spid27s     The Service Broker endpoint is in disabled or stopped state.
2024-07-04 05:01:24.51 spid27s     The Database Mirroring endpoint is in disabled or stopped state.
2024-07-04 05:01:24.52 spid27s     Service Broker manager has started.
2024-07-04 05:01:24.53 spid9s      Recovery is complete. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.

Now my DB container is exited, I can't figure it out why. Also I want to achieve the a continuous migration process though my migration files which are created by Visual Studio.
How can solve my problem and integrate the continuous migration?

Aside... SA_PASSWORD has been deprecated for a couple of years now. You should be using MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD instead, as per the documentation.

Docker is designed to run only one foreground task per container. /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr & starts SQL Server in the background so the container will probably exit after about sixty seconds after /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd and sleep 30s have finished executing. Have a read through the mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server documentation and look for the link titled "using an entrypoint.sh and setup.sql scripts to create a database." It runs the initialization/setup script in the background and SQL Server in the foreground.
